# Can someone tell me how to turn pic 1 to pic 2?

Tags: lighting, color, color-management

[image]

[image]

colors in pic 1 are a bit 2d, where's pic 2 looks very clay like. What's the difference between these 2 and how can I take pic 1 to pic 2?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Maybe put the Specular value of the Principled BSDF at 0 and also give a bit of Emission (0.2 for example) with the same Emission color as the Base Color? It will create a very soft material, that will look like gum

Answer (score 1):

One big difference is lighting. The first example appears to be illuminated with point source or directional lights while the second is larger, more spread out illumination.

Try a sun lamp with a small size - you’ll get much sharper shadows.